# Python Mongodb sorting too big, how to use index?

Tags: python, mongodb, loops, indexing

I'm trying to iterate in Python over all elements of a large Mongodb database.

Usually, I do:

```
mgclient = MongoClient('mongodb://user:pwd@0.0.0.0:27017')
mgdb = mgclient['mongo']
mgcol = mgdb['name']
for mg_ob in mgcol.find().sort('Date').sort('time'):
    #DOTHINGS
```

But it says "Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit".

So I created an index named 'SortedTime', but I don't understand how I can use it now.

Basically, I'm trying to have something like:

```
mgclient = MongoClient('mongodb://user:pwd@0.0.0.0:27017')
mgdb = mgclient['mongo']
mgcol = mgdb['name']
for mg_ob in mgcol.find()['SortedTime']:
    #DOTHINGS
```

Any ideas ? A little hand would be much appreciated.

I hope this post will help others. Thank you very much

**Update:**
I managed to make it work thanks to Joe. After I created the Index:

```
resp = mgcol.create_index(
[
("date", 1),
("time", 1)
]
)

print ("index response:", resp)
```

What I did was just:

```
mgclient = MongoClient('mongodb://user:pwd@0.0.0.0:27017')
mgdb = mgclient['mongo']
mgcol = mgdb['name']
for mg_ob in mgcol.find():
    #DOTHINGS
```

No need to use the index name.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is sorting on 2 fields, `Date` and `time`, so you will need an index that includes these fields first in the key specification.

Working from the mongo shell, you might use the [createIndex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/index.html) shell helper:

```
db.getSiblingDB("mongo").getCollection("name").createIndex({Date:1, time:1})
```

Working from the client side, you might use the [createIndexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/createIndexes/index.html) database command.

Once the index has been created, query just like you did before and the mongod's query executor should use the index.

You can use [explain()](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html?highlight=explain#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.explain) to get detailed query execution stages to see which indexes were considered and the comparative performance of each.

Comment: Hi Joe, thank you very much for the answer. The index I created use the 2 fields. I still don't understand how I should use it ? mgcol = mgdb['SortedTime'] this way (does not work) ?

Comment: I got it ! Posting the answer. Thank you for your time :)